# Identify buffer areas which meet with lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a large series of points representing street posts which I have created a buffer for. I now want to find which of these buffer areas do and don't meet with a network of lines (representing electrical cables).

How would I go about doing this in ArcMap? Ideally I would have a final output of 2 layers, one showing the areas which do meet a line, and the other that doesn't. However preference is for the areas which do not intersect any lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcMap, add both the buffer feature class and the cable feature class to your table of contents. Then go to the Selection tab and choose 'Select by Location'. A dialog box will open. With this, you'll be able to select buffer features that intersect the cable features. Once you have made your selection, right-click on the buffer layer in your table of contents, and select Data -> Export... You will get a dialog box that lets you export selected features to a new feature class.

Once you have your feature class of buffer features that intersect the cable features, open the attribute table of your original buffer feature class. In the table, press the 'Switch Selection' button. Now once again perform your Data -> Export..., and you will have your second feature class, of those buffers that do not intersect the cable features.